# Instantiating and using ppc440 core in Virtex 5 FPGA

Tags: virtex-series-fpga

I am new to Virtex 5 which has an embedded PPC440 core in it (XC5VFX70T). I am using the Xilinx ML507 board for my design.

I created the embedded core using XPS and instantiated it in my HDL project. As peripherals, I am using a DDR2 controller, BRAM, SRAM, one UART and a few GPIOs. However, I could not see any address/data bus ports from the embedded core which I can use in the FPGA fabric.

I have a few RTL IP cores which require memory mapping. How do I connect these IP cores to PPC440 core? Also there are a few registers implemented in the FPGA fabric which are used for system initialization. I want the PPC440 core to write to these registers during initialization. How can I achieve this if the embedded core doesn't have address/data bus as external ports?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Xilinx UG200 and the MPLB interface. This looks like the port that you will need to connect your memory mapped peripherals to, probably with a decent amount of interface logic.

Comment: I will try that. Should I define it as a custom peripheral and connect it to MPLB? I guess I will have to develop the drivers for custom peripherals also.

Comment: Yeah, I think so. I presume you just implement the peripherals in HDL and then connect them to the ppc440 instance. As far as the software goes, I think it just ends up being memory mapped somewhere. I'm not sure how much flexibility there is as far as configuring that. I have never used the ppc cores in a design before.